# CKAN login redirects to URL with missing root_path

Tags: ckan

I install CKAN 2.9 in a local Debian Buster VM, by following the instructions on how to install from source and deployment.
I am using NGINX and have the `proxy_pass` in place and nginx and `ckan.root_path = /sfb1153/ckan` in ckan.ini. All runs weel

However **when I try to login at http://192.168.60.103/sfb1153/ckan/user/login, after submitting the form, the path that CKAN redirects to is missing the root_path (`/sfb1153/ckan`) and leads me to a 404.**

Here is the nginx access log:

```
192.168.60.1 - - [17/Oct/2020:13:11:27 +0000] "POST /sfb1153/ckan/login_generic?came_from=/sfb1153/ckan/user/logged_in HTTP/1.1" 302 379 "http://192.168.60.103/sfb1153/ckan/user/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"

192.168.60.1 - - [17/Oct/2020:13:11:27 +0000] "GET /user/logged_in?came_from=%2Fsfb1153%2Fckan%2Fuser%2Flogged_in&__logins=0 HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "http://192.168.60.103/sfb1153/ckan/user/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"
```

Notice that:

- POST goes to: `/sfb1153/ckan/login_generic` which is correct
- response GET goes to: `/user/logged_in` which is missing the root_path and as a result returns a 404

Any ideas how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The same value as the `ckan.root_path` in ckan.ini needs to be added to `post_login_url` and `post_logout_url` variables of /etc/ckan/default/who.ini

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value of the site url in the .env file or the configuration file with the ip address.

Comment: Thanks. And that's what I have, in the ckan.ini file

 As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-site-url)

> This setting [ckan.site_url] should only contain the protocol (e.g. http://), host (e.g. www.example.com) and (optionally) the port (e.g. :8080). In particular, if you have mounted CKAN at a path other than / then the mount point must not be included in ckan.site_url. Instead, you need to set ckan.root_path.
in this case the:

```
ckan.site_url = http://192.168.60.103,
ckan.root_url = /sfb1153/ckan
```